# Spring mvc: Dynamic 404 page

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, http-status-code-404

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

This is my current configuration for 404 errors.

What I want:
When a person types www.host.com/word . I want the string "word" as input for my search url (which is www.host.com/search.do?keyword).

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Map `/` to your `DispatcherServlet` (see [section 16.2](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet) of the Spring reference documentation) and set up a URI template as shown in [section 16.3.2.1](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates). For example, you could set up a request mapping like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{keyword}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView doSearch(@PathVariable("keyword") String keyword)
{
  // forward to your search page
}
```

Comment: <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>frontend</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>frontend</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

Comment: Yes, I've amended my answer to link to the relevant section in the Spring documentation.  If my answer solved your problem please accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Comment: Is it true that everything behind host.com/ is now mapped to the dispatcher? Because my homepage doesnt show up right anymore (css, javascript).

Comment: Yes.  You could map the servlet to search/ instead so search/{keyword} be the url instead.

Comment: Can you give me an example of this please? What to i need to put in the web.xml?

Comment: There is an example in [section 16.2](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet) of the Spring docs - it shows you exactly what to put in web.xml.